# Can I start Win 8 background task manualy

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

I am using C# for my application, and its vital that the live tile starts its updates, right after the person logs in his PC. For now the updates start no earlier than 15 minutes, because I am using a time trigger for the live tile updates. Is there any way to trigger the task manually, or is there some other way that I can make my live tile to start its updates from when the user has logged on the system?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to run your background task immediately.  However, periodic tile updates or push notifications can be used update a live tile upon user log-on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the background task manually, but you can simply create a shared library with the code that your background task runs, and call it directly from the background task. Then you can manually call that code whenever you want to manually trigger it from your application.

Comment: Well my problem is that when I start my computer and log on to it, the task starts after 15 minutes, because the timer triggers the task only at the 15 minute mark. So is there a way to make it trigger once when the person logs in, and then each 15 minutes?

Comment: Yes you can do that, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx. You need to use the SessionConnected system event. You application will need to run as a lock screen app though.

Answer (score 0):

The UserPresent SystemTriggerType might be what your after. The way I am thinking about doing it is having both Time and System Triggers, so every 15mins and when the user is unlocks the device.
I don't think you get anywhere near as much CPU time with the SystemTrigger tho, but its better than nothing
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The DispatcherTimer can help you fire off events at set intervals. You can add the code in the App() constructor:

```
    // _dispatcherTimer is probably a class level variable.
    DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;


    // How often
    uint _DoSomethingInterval = 500;

    // Set up a DispatchTimer
    _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _dispatcherTimer.Tick += DoSomething;

    // If you like lambdas, do this
    //_dispatcherTimer.Tick += (sender, object ) => 
    // { Debug.WriteLine("time passed so do something"); }


    _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)_desiredReportInterval);

    // The callback for the timer
    private void DoSomething(object sender, object args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("time passed so do something"); 
    }
```